# Sympy - Float has no attribute sqrt

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, sqrt

I am working on a code snippet, where I am unable to debug the issue, any suggestions would be appreciated.

The error is attribute error: Float object has no attribute sqrt

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

rho_l = 1000;
rho_g= 1.225;
sigma = 0.072
nu = 0.001;
Q = rho_g/ rho_l;
u = 14.8;

k = Symbol('k', real=True)
w1 = -2*nu*k**2
w2 = 4* (nu**2) * (k**4);
w3 = - Q* (u**2) * (k**2);
w4 = - sigma * (k**3)/ rho_l;
w = w1 + sqrt(w2+w3+w4);

print (w)
wprime = w.diff(k)
print (wprime)

ko = solve(wprime, k) # solve fprime = 0 with respect to x
ko = ko[0]
print (ko)

ws = lambdify (k, w, 'numpy');
print (type(ko))
print (ws(ko))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because `numpy` apparently doesn't know how to handle sympy.core.numbers.Float types (https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.numbers.Float). Therefore, the `numpy` sqrt raises the exception when you call `ws`. To fix, pass `sympy` to `lambdify` instead of `numpy`.

```py
ws = lambdify (k, w, 'sympy');
print (type(ko)) # >> <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
print (ws(ko))   # >> -82.5885350883393
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could convert the `sympy.Float` to a regular float using `float()` and replace `k0` by `float(k0)` .

```
ws = lambdify(k, w, 'numpy');
print(type(float(ko)))  # >> <class 'float'>
print(ws(float(ko)))    # >> -82.58853508833931
```

Comment: You probably mean `ws = lambdify(k, w, 'numpy')`

Comment: Right - thank you! I have changed `ws = lambdify(k, w, 'sympy')` to `ws = lambdify(k, w, 'numpy')`